# Systemd files appearing in /tmp folder

Tags: systemd, tmp

I seem to be getting weird folders in my `/tmp` file. They disappear after opening the `/tmp` file for a few seconds.

What are they?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far the second folder in the screenshot is concerned, your hostname.d service has `PrivateTmp=true` declared in the systemd file, that's why it is appearing here. You can disable this behavior by updating `/etc/systemd/system/hostnamed.service` file and changing the value of `PrivateTmp=false`.

For more details, you can see this: https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2012-11-05-fedora-private-tmp/

Comment: Related, from systemd.io: [Using `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` safely](https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES/)